# Making OpenGraph v1.0 calls with the newer Facebook iOS sdk(3.18)

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

According to the Facebook [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBRequest/) it's  possible to make OpenGraph v1.0 calls with the newer SDK by either using the overrideVersionPartWith call, or manually pre-pending the call with "v1.0"

However, when I make a call such as /v1.0/{id} I get a "Unknown path components : /{id}" error. How do I fix this?

Comment: You can only call API v1.0 if your app was created before 4/30/2014 and it will only be possible to call API v1.0 until 4/30/2015 even if your app was created before that date.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My app was created before  4/30/2014, and I know that openGraph  is getting depreciated on 4/30/2015. Also, the same code works with older SDK versions.

Comment: The app was active before 4/30/2014? What is your app id and I can check

Comment: Indeed. The app id is 169340843260345

Comment: Ok, that app can use API v1.0. Can you test doing the query in Graph Explorer. And if that doesn't work tell us exactly what query you do

Comment: The calls work fine in the Explorer. Some queries that fail on the app - "/v1.0/736819001", "/v1.0/me". Both return "Unknown path components". Also, both work with on older SDK

Comment: What does your code look like? And what is the exact error

Comment: [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:"v1.0/me" parameters:params HTTPMethod:"GET" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            [task success:result];
        } else {
            [facebook_Util handleError:error task:task closeSession:false];
        }
    }];

Comment: So you don't use overrideVersionPartWith?

Comment: No. I directly prepend the url with the version number - the documentation (link  in the original post) states that it's an acceptable way of doing that.

Comment: Does "/v1.0/me" work? I wonder if you call overrideVersionPartWith somewhere so the url becomes /v2.0/v1.0/me or something

Comment: as in adding the "/" at the beginning? No...

Comment: Then I would suggest that you capture the traffic to see what http request you are actually doing

Comment: are you suggesting that the Facebook SDK is randomly changing my requests?

Comment: No idea. But something changes it. Otherwise it wouldn't work in Graph Explorer but not in your app

Comment: It seems like the Facebook SDK prepends /v2.0 to all calls (so I get /v2.0/v1.0/me) - this goes against the what it says in the FAcebook documentation

Comment: File a bug and use overrideversionpartwith

Comment: fair enough - thanks!

Comment: bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1484718591798418/